# Styling TinyMCE produced tables with PHP (Hor Zebra)

Tags: php, tinymce

I am using the self hosting that I have downloaded from https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/. It allows me to do the What-you-see-is-what-you-get editing.

My problem is when I am inserting tables, they come with out any styling, and therefor are difficult to read.

**Here is what TinyMCE table insert looks like:**

[image]

This produces the following HTML code:

```
<p>Table example:</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 192px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 48px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Headcell 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Headcell 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Headcell 3</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Headcell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 48px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 3</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 48px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Odd 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Odd 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Odd 3</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Odd 4</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 48px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 3</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 48px;">Bodycell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 25%;">Odd 1</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">Odd 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">Odd 3</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">Odd 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**However I would like it to produce the following:**
[image]

```
<p>Table example:</p>
<table class="hor-zebra">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">
    <span>Headcell 1</span>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">
    <span>Headcell 2</span>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">
    <span>Headcell 3</span>
   </th>
   <th scope="col">
    <span>Headcell 4</span>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    Bodycell 1
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 2
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 3
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 4
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 1
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 2
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 3
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 4
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    Bodycell 1
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 2
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 3
   </td>
   <td>
    Bodycell 4
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 1
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 2
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 3
   </td>
   <td class="odd">
    Bodycell 4
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

(This is the CSS if anyone wants it)

```
/* Tables Hor Zebra
------------------------------------------------------------------ */
table.hor-zebra {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing:0;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead {
  border-top: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead>tr>th {
    background: #e2e2e2;
    border-top: #ffffff 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #000;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
    padding: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td.odd {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
}
table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td.important {
    background: #fff7e5;
    border-bottom: #eabc63 1px solid;
}
table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td.danger {
    background: #ffe7e5;
    border-bottom: #ff4940 1px solid;
    border-top: #ff4940 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr:hover td {
    background: #faf4f2;
}
```

**Solution?**
I am using PHP and I get the text from TinyMCE with

$inp_text = $_POST['inp_text'];

I was thinking of using the PHP function str_replace to just replace the code that I did not want to appear, but I don't think it would be sufficient. Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE generates the HTML for inserted tables. They can be styled using CSS.

You can inject CSS into the TinyMCE editor by either linking to a remote stylesheet using the `content_css` `tiny.init()` configuration option:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

...or by including the desired styling in the `content_style` option:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style